# Single chip solution for power suply, 5v and 3.3v output

Tags: voltage-regulator

Im developing a sensor that needs 3.3 and 5 volts, my actual design use a simple combination of a lm7805 and a lm7833, given the fact that space efficiency is important in this project, I  wonder, is there a single chip solution to have that dual output? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [list](http://www.analog.com/en/power-management/multi-output-regulators/products/index.html) from Analog Devices of multi output voltage regulators. And [here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCV8614-D.PDF) is another from On Semiconductor